# Can't render items using Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm working on a react native app but i'm not able to render items using Flatlist

Here is my code:

```js
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <AppointmentModeSwitch navigation={navigation} active="next" />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', paddingHorizontal: wp(1) }}>
                {scheduleAppointmentsOrganizedAndFiltered && scheduleAppointmentsOrganizedAndFiltered.length > 0 ? (
                    <FlatList
                        data={scheduleAppointmentsOrganizedAndFiltered}
                        style={{ marginTop: hp(1), marginBottom: hp(4) }}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return (
                                <Appointment
                                    key={String(item.therapist.name + Math.random)}
                                    appointment={item}
                                    navigation={navigation}
                                />
                            );
                        }}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.date_time.toString()}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: hp(5) }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 24, color: '#006D77', fontFamily: fontConfig.bold }}>
                            Não tem consultas agendadas.
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

And the Appointment is here

```js
const Appointment = ({ appointment, navigation }) => {
    const [isMeetingModalVisible, setMeetingModalVisibility] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <View style={{
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                shadowOffset: {
                    width: 2,
                    height: 2,
                },
                shadowOpacity: 0.5,
                shadowRadius: 5,
                elevation: 5,
                padding: hp(2), backgroundColor: 'white', marginLeft: wp(3), marginRight: wp(3), marginTop: hp(2), borderRadius: 10
            }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", maxWidth: wp(150) }}>
                    <FastImage
                        source={{ uri: appointment.therapist.avatar, priority: FastImage.priority.high }}
                        style={{
                            width: hp(12),
                            height: hp(12),
                            borderRadius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            marginRight: wp(2),
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "white",
                        }}
                    />
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: wp(2) }}>

                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: fontConfig.bold, color: 'black' }} numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit>{appointment.therapist.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: fontConfig.regular, color: 'gray', marginTop: hp(2), marginRight: wp(1) }} numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit>{appointment.status} | {appointment.localization}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: fontConfig.regular, color: 'black', marginTop: hp(2) }}>{formatDateTime(appointment.date_time)}</Text>

                    </View>
                    {appointment.localization === 'Online' &&
                        <Ionicons name="videocam" color={'black'} size={25} style={{ marginLeft: wp(3) }}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MeetingScreen", {
                                appointment: appointment
                            })}
                        />
                    }
                </View>
            </View>


        </>
    );
};
```

If the scheduleAppointmentsOrganizedAndFiltered == 0, that's ok, and i'm able to see " Não tem consultas agendadas.", however if scheduleAppointmentsOrganizedAndFiltered > 0 the app crashes in internal testing (android). I'm not able to reproduce the issue in my local env.
Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

I've tried to using a state like isLoading in order to render data only after the isLoading is set to false, but nothing works.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: in my local everything works fine, but when I try it on internal test in play console the app just crashes. basically, I click in the section to navigate to this screen and the app crashes.